# how to show alert after comparing the values of UITextField in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have five uitextfiedls i want that sum of the four textfields should not be greater than the first textfiedl value

Like below

```
    textField1.text=@"20";
    textField2.text=@"10";
    textField3.text=@"4";
    textField4.text=@"4";
    textField5.text=@"2";
```

In above the textfiled1=20 and sum of all other is 22 i want that when user enter data more than that then it show the alert.

Comment: 10 + 4 + 4 + 2 = 20, not 22 - might want to fix your example.

Comment: @Its not the point to vote down the question

Comment: I agree - an arithmetic error is not a reason to vote it down, and seeing as there's no comment explaining the vote down, it makes it hard to improve.  I don't think you should be able to vote down without giving a reason. Upvoted to compensate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sumOfOthers = [[textField2 text] intValue] + [[textField3 text] intValue] + [[textField4 text] intValue]  + [[textField5 text] intValue];
int firstValue = [[textField1 text] intValue]
if (sumOfOthers  > firstValue)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"The message you want."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: If you're not using ARC, remember to add `autorelease` to the end of the alloc-init line. Or `release` after `show`.

Comment: Thanks @SveinHalvorHalvorsen It's amazing how quickly using ARC can make you complacent about such things :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(( [textField1.text intValue]>=[[textField2 text] intValue] + [[textField3 text] intValue] + [[textField4 text] intValue]  + [[textField5 text] intValue])) {
    //Your alertView Code 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls keep in mind that all suggested answers must be implemented in an `UITextFieldDelegate`, most probably in an `textFieldDidEndEditing` method.

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this:

```
  NSInteger field1 = textField1.text.intValue;
  NSInteger field2 = textField2.text.intValue;
  NSInteger field3 = textField3.text.intValue;
  NSInteger field4 = textField4.text.intValue;
  NSInteger field5 = textField5.text.intValue;

  if(field1 >= (field2 + field3 + field4 + field5)) {
    //Your alertView Code 
  }
```